# Issues implementing a simple linux shell

Tags: c, shell, operating-system

I've been struggling with this simple linux shell for hours now, and for some reason I just can't get the most basic thing working correctly. Something is seriously messed up with how I handle my input or something, because one example of how this shell doesn't work is the mkdir command. It randomly won't create a random directory I never tried to create, and every time I do create a directory it manages to create some other ones with random names I obviously didn't create. Something is messed up and I just have no clue, because I've been outputting my final argument array and it looks fine from there. Can someone please take a look at this for me.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
while(1){
    char line[100], *temp, *split[15];
    int child_id;
    printf("$ ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';

    temp = strtok(line, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while(temp != NULL){
        split[i] = temp;
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    char *args[i];
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        args[j] = split[j];
        printf("%s\n", args[j]);
    }
    child_id = fork();
    if(child_id == 0){
        execvp(args[0], args);
        exit(0);
    }else{
        wait(&child_id);
    }


  }

}
```

Comment: Why bother with the `args` array at all? Just use `split` directly...

Comment: Because I wasn't sure if my original array was causing the issue by having char* that weren't used, although I suppose since I never alloc'ed them it wouldn't have been an issue. I was just being overly cautious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `execvp()`, the final element of the `args` array must be `NULL` (this tells the kernel where the list of command line arguments ends).

You should be able to do this by adding `split[i] = NULL;` after the `strtok()` loop (oh, and no need to copy the array to `args` as mentioned in the comment above, just use `split`).

Comment: Thank you so much, in the 6 years I've been programming, I have never run into a error that I couldn't solve before, until this one. It was driving me crazy for hours...Thanks again for your help, things are working great now.